How to automatically capitalise text entered in a specific cell in Excel with Excel VBA
I want the text in a specific cell to always be uppercase, without having to use a formula, regarless of whether or not I am typing in capital letters.
I have tried using code in Excel VBA but it does not work.
This is the code I used:
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

  If Target.Address = Range("A1").Address Then
    Target.Value = UCase(Target.Value)
  End If

End Sub


Did you put that code in the code module for the worksheet?  If you put a breakpoint in the code is it reached when you change the value in A1??
